# JMS 2.0 support in Mule

Tags: jms, mule

I was trying out for the possibility to use JMS 2.0 in Mule. In my research I found that ActiveMQ supports JMS 2.0 with the combination of Spring 4.1.0.RELEASE [here](http://shengwangi.blogspot.in/2014/10/spring-jms-with-activemq-helloworld-example-send.html)

Can any one suggest the ways to use JMS 2.0 in Mule ESB using above please.

Thanks .!!

Comment: No. ActiveMQ does not support JMS2.0 yet. The article explicitly states that `For now, 2014-10, ActiveMQ only implements the interfaces defined in  JMS 1.1 version.  `. This is still true. However, HornetQ does support JMS2.0 and the HornetQ code base has been donated to the ActiveMQ project. So in the future, there will likely be a JMS 2.0 compatible ActiveMQ release.

Answer (score 1):

[Mule 4 JMS connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/jms/jms-connector) is fully complaint with JMS 2.0.

JMS connector is

> Fully compliant with JMS 2.0, 1.1, and 1.0.2 specifications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no JMS2.0 support in MuleESB at this very moment, just [1.0.2b and 1.1](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/jms-transport-reference). It has been on the radar for a while but no plans to support it yet.

Which features of JMS2.0 do you need? If it's competing consumers on topics are supported with activemq and 1.1 with [virtual topics](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html), and there is also a [more poweful scheduled](http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html) send than what it is in 2.0.

Comment: As stated by Sudarshan, Mule 4 supports JMS 2.0.